# Insertar un arreglo dinamico en una tabla con X campos - PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una dificultad que no logro sortear, y quisiera algo de ayuda.

Tengo un arreglo dinámico, este va desde 1 hasta 5 elementos dentro.
Como por ejemplo:

```
$arreglo = [1];
$arreglo = [1,2,3,4,5]
$arreglo = [1,3,5]
```

Estos datos, de entre 1 a 5, debo insertarlos dentro de una tabla MYSQL, que tiene disponibilidad para esos 5 elementos.
La idea es que el insert quede de modo que el 3er arreglo se cumpla como la tabla de más abajo. Los dos anteriores los puedo hacer, el problema es con el 3er ejemplo.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | null | 3 | null | 5 |

Lo que necesito es realizar el insert de tal modo que vaya agregando los datos correctamente a cada columna, pero no logro obtener dicho resultado

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO tabla (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
           VALUES (
             [value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5]
           )";
```

Estaba probando hacer el uso de for o foreach, pero acá es donde no se como decirle a cual columna debe o no ir.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($arreglo); $i++){
    $insert = .......;
}
```

Comment: si tienes un dato este debería ir a la primera columna o se debe de especificar la columna?

Comment: un dato puede ir directamente a la primera columna, como en el primer arreglo, el tema es cuando son más y saltados. Quizás necesite algún indice en el arreglo, para saber cual va en que posicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que en el array inicial no existe ninguna referencia a la columna es imposible determinar a que columna deben añadirse los valores cuando falta alguno de los intermedios.

Podrías modificar el array que recibes para que o bien siempre envíe los cinco valores que esperas, pero aquellos que no tenga valor a `null` o bien construir el array utilizando las claves del mismo como referencias a la columna.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$array = [
    0 => 'valor1',
    2 => 'valor3',
    4 => 'valor5',
];

echo $array[0] ?? 'valor por defecto'; // valor1
echo $array[1] ?? 'valor por defecto'; // valor por defecto
echo $array[2] ?? 'valor por defecto'; // valor3
echo $array[3] ?? 'valor por defecto'; // valor por defecto
echo $array[4] ?? 'valor por defecto'; // valor5


$query = 'INSERT INTO tabla (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

// Imagino que ya tendrás tu conexion iniciada
if (!$stmt = $mysqliConection->prepare($query)) {
    throw new \Exception("Error prepare query");
}

$stmt->bind_param(
    'sssss',
    $array[0] ?? null,
    $array[1] ?? null,
    $array[2] ?? null,
    $array[3] ?? null,
    $array[4] ?? null
);

$stmt->execute();
```

Ejemplo con valores nulos

```php
<?php

$array = [
    0 => 'valor1',
    1 => null,
    2 => 'valor3',
    3 => null,
    4 => 'valor5',
];

if (count($array) < 5) {
    throw new \Exception("Error Processing Request");
}

echo $array[0]; // valor1
echo $array[1]; // null
echo $array[2]; // valor3
echo $array[3]; // null
echo $array[4]; // valor5

$query = 'INSERT INTO tabla (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

// Imagino que ya tendrás tu conexion iniciada
if (!$stmt = $mysqliConection->prepare($query)) {
    throw new \Exception("Error prepare query");
}

$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3], $array[4]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir las columnas en un arreglo y con un `foreach` obtener la columna correspondiente mediante el valor menos 1 para obtener el indice:

```php
<?php

$datos = [1,3,5];
$columnas = array('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5');

$campos = '';
$values = '';

foreach($datos as $dato){
    $campos .= $columnas[$dato-1].',';
    $values .= $dato.',';
}

$len = strlen($campos);

if($len > 0){
    $campos = substr($campos, 0, -1);
    $values = substr($values, 0, -1);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tabla ($campos) VALUES ($values)";
}
?>
```

Resultado:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (col1,col3,col5) VALUES (1,3,5)
```

Tal vez le falta refactorización al código pero es una opción.